# Why submitting a form with Ajax it's not setting model data using ModelDriven in Struts 2?

Tags: java, forms, struts2, struts2-jquery, model-driven

I have following situation in code:

**Action class:**

```
@NameSpace("/")
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Car> {
    private Car car = new Cart();

    @Override
    public Car getModel() {
        return car;
    }

    @Action(value = "pageAction", results = {name = SUCCESS, location = "myPage", type="tiles"})
    public String showPage() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "formSubmitAction", results = {name = SUCCESS, location = "results.jsp"})
    public String formSubmitAction() {
        System.out.println(car);
        // everything has default values (nulls)
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**View for myPage location:**

```
<s:form 
    namespace="/" 
    action="pageAction" 
    method="post" >
    <s:push value="model">
        <s:textfield name="color" />
        <s:textfield name="manufacturer" />
        <sj:submit
            href="formSubmitAction"         
            targets="output"  />
    </s:push>
</s:form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**results.jsp:**

renders empty content into `div#output`

```
<s:property value="%{model}" />
<s:property value="%{model.color}" />
<s:property value="%{model.manufacturer}" />
```

I wonder why is that happening? Model data is not updated after submit.

I'm using [struts2-jquery submit tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag).

When I'm using simple form submit without Ajax the model is being updated,
but I want to load data asynchronously with Ajax.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you use modeldriven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add ID to `form` and to `sj:submit` tag. But I don't know why submit tag inside form wasn't working properly. The correct code is below:

```
<s:form 
    id="formId"
    namespace="/" 
    action="pageAction" 
    method="post" >
    <s:push value="model">
        <s:textfield name="color" />
        <s:textfield name="manufacturer" />
        <sj:submit
            formIds="formId"
            href="formSubmitAction"         
            targets="output"  />
    </s:push>
</s:form>
```

**EDIT**

As it turns out you only have to add ID to `form`, and everything works :)
look at link in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) pushes a model on top of the `valueStack`. So you can access model properties directly.

```
<s:property value="%{color}" />
<s:property value="%{manufacturer}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help, I found solution which I'll describe in a minute